# Python beautiful soup and requests submit form data on post url

Tags: forms, beautifulsoup, python-requests, http-post, python-requests-html

How can i post form data on the url:  http://washington.kdmid.ru/queue-en/Visitor.aspx

When i submit form data with below fields i am getting same page in response instead of redirect to next page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

location_url = "http://washington.kdmid.ru/queue-en/visitor.aspx"
s = requests.Session()

main_page = s.get(location_url)

main_html = BeautifulSoup(main_page.text)


c_form = main_html.find_all("form")[0]
c_form_submit = c_form.attrs["action"]
data = {e.attrs.get("name"): e.attrs.get("value") for e in c_form.find_all("input")}

data["ctl00$MainContent$txtFam"] = "bsssabassra"
data["ctl00$MainContent$txtIm"] = "Akssssshassya"
data["ctl00$MainContent$txtOt"] = "a"
data["ctl00$MainContent$txtTel"] = "1122334455"
data["ctl00$MainContent$txtEmail"] = "akssbsars2@gmail.com"
data["ctl00$MainContent$DDL_Day"] = 1
data["ctl00$MainContent$DDL_Month"] = 1
data["ctl00$MainContent$TextBox_Year"] = 1993
data["ctl00$MainContent$DDL_Mr"] = "MR"
data["ctl00$MainContent$txtCode"] = captcha_txt
data["ctl00$MainContent$ButtonA"] = "Next"
import json; json.dumps(data)
submit_captcha_resp = s.post("http://washington.kdmid.ru/queue-en/visitor.aspx", 
data=json.dumps(data))
final_page = BeautifulSoup(submit_captcha_resp.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

It wont redirect, because it's not a browser. BS don't run the JS scripts or HTML code. But you get the response.
You should use one of these:

```py
submit_captcha_resp = s.post("yourLongURL", json=data)
```

or

```py
submit_captcha_resp = s.post("yourLongURL", data=data)
```

json.dumps() is used to convert a JSON to a string but you don't need that because the webpage which you are posting data uses HTML  tag and form tag posts the data without converting it to string. So you shouldn't convert it to a string. You should post it in JSON format.

And as @dharmey said: If you get a 404, you should set a user agent as a popular web browser. For example:

```json
{"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
```

And I think now you have bigger problems like passing the Captcha.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be posting the data in the wrong way. You could try

```
submit_captcha_resp = s.post("http://washington.kdmid.ru/queue-en/visitor.aspx", 
json=data)
```

Instead of `data=json.dumps(data))`

If this dosen't work / the site requires actual form data, try to pass in some `headers`, as they might be required for the server to recieve the request correctly.

You could just include

```
headers = {
   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36'
}

submit_captcha_resp = s.post("http://washington.kdmid.ru/queue-en/visitor.aspx", 
headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

to start out.

Comment: Is it running at you end?